# How to get awarded a PhD without actually doing it?

Tags: phd

I know that I am an independent researcher and I have recently done research in a linear programming problem in my job and was able to get the same objective value within 24 hours, which IBM's Cplex was taking around 72 hours. I did something which the MS and PhD guys actually failed.

But I don't have enough time and money required to do MS or PhD. How can I help myself?

Basically the question is how to become a scientist in the field of mathematics, I mean invent or discover some formula/theory/assumption and then get the degree of Phd as an award/reward. Obviously someone would be needed as a guide who tells me the area of research, where other researchers did not succeed.

Comment: There are no shortcuts to a PhD. If money is your concern, search this site for questions regarding funding. But as the question stands it sounds like you are mostly interested in cutting corners, perhaps even in acquiring a fake PhD from a scam "university". Don't do it. Nobody will take you seriously. Also, the people whom you are asking this question here are or were working hard to obtain their degrees. They are unlikely to have much sympathy for your question. (In fact, I'm already slightly annoyed.)

Comment: Nothing like cutting corners, I am basically looking for a platform where I can keep submitting my research works and also keep on getting directions and if I do something great, I get awarded with a PhD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to complete a PhD in Industrial Engineering without any coursework? (US/Europe)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/is-it-possible-to-complete-a-phd-in-industrial-engineering-without-any-coursewor)

Comment: @DeepakMishra you mean you want to make the research, write papers and every requirement for phd but without an institute? In my country this is called individual phd studies or something like that. No fundings are provided for such a research, but when you fulfill the requirements of a phd, you can submit your dissertation to a doctoral school and may obtain the phd degree. Fundings can be given by companies though, even through universities, but in that case case you have to follow their needs. Otherwise, I doubt you can get money as a standalone person a priori for your research.

Comment: @BalazsToth yes something like individual phd with some direction.

Comment: See [PhD by published work](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101343/17254)

Comment: How is this unclear? OP wants to get awarded a PhD without actually doing it, which is a well-defined goal. It might be an impossible goal, but it's still well-defined and so not unclear. Voting to reopen.

Comment: that's funny, too many downvotes, comments and now question is on hold, Am I insecuring a lot of people?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! This question displays some naïveté about academia. When combined with a rather poor question title, it looks as if you're trolling the community, hence the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks @eykanal, actually that's not true, I just want to do something equivalent to a PhD independently and I don't want to pay for it, I actually want to earn from it. Usually with the employer, I do earn but I lose the royalty/credit/copyright of it.

Comment: It is well known that you can obtain a PhD just by submitting a thesis, in many countries. Japan is perhaps most famous for them. But then you need to pay for a review fee (because someone actually has to take their time to review it): say, at least ~50000 JPY, but in most countries more than that (would be more like 5000 EUR). You just can't make money from doing independent research, sorry: you need to be employed to do research in order to get paid.

Comment: @xuq01 Actually you should have. I want a platform which allows us to do that (drop out from the school but still be able to do the independent research). I am not saying that every independent research deserves money, but if your research is used by someone, you should be able to ask rent of it.

Comment: @DeepakMishra It sounds as though you want all the benefits of being in a university - somebody advising you, going over your work, etc - without paying for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are planning to continue doing research and are attempting to "convert" that published work into a PhD.

First off, do not fall for the trap of giving your money to a [diploma mill](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/what-is-a-diploma-mill?s=1|122.8316). You will waste your own money and time and end up with a *worthless degree.*

The second challenge you will face is that virtually all PhD-granting institutions have what is known as a **residency requirement**: you *must* spend some time, typically at least one year, on the campus of the university as part of the degree program There often is not a requirement as to *when* this must take place: it could be at the beginning or end of the process or sometime in between, nor must it necessarily be contiguous. However, it is often phrased in the form of "X semesters," which does place some constraints.

So you need to look for a university which will accommodate such a plan (not many would allow you to work completely independently), and will allow you to work as little as possible on-site. Or perhaps you can find an employer who can support your research ambitions—many will allow and even financially support employees to obtain advanced degrees (particularly master's).